# Name lookup of qualified base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, name-lookup

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace D
{
    struct S { S(){std::cout << "D::S\n";} };
}

struct S { S(){std::cout << "S\n";} };

struct X: D::S
{
    X(): S() {}        // (1)
    // X(): D::S() {}  // (2)

    void f() { S s; }
};

int main() { X x; x.f(); }
```

Output from g++ is:

```
D::S
D::S
```

My questions are:

- How does (1) work - I would have though that the name of the base class is `D::S` specifically
- Are (1) and (2) both required to work?
- Why does `S s;` inside `f()` refer to `D::S` and not `::S` ?

Comment: `S` in `X` is the *injected class name* referring to `D::S`.

Comment: [class.base.init]/3 guarantees that both (1) and (2) would work. "A *mem-initializer-list* can initialize a base class using any *class-or-decltype* that denotes that base class type."

Comment: @0x499602D2 I didn't realize (until reading Jonathan's answer) that it is the injected class name *injected into D::S* (not into X) and so it is in X's scope because items from X's base class are in X's scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the body of the class `D::S` the name `S` refers to itself, obviously. This is called the "injected class name". You can think of it as though there is a public member typedef in `D::S` with its own name, `S`.

> - How does (1) work - I would have though that the name of the base class is D::S specifically

`X` derives from `D::S`, because you said so in the base class list of `X`.

A derived class has access to the names declared in a base class, so name lookup in `X` first looks at its own members and its base class' members, then looks for names in the enclosing scope outside `X`. Because the injected class name `S` is a member of `D::S`, it gets found in `X`, that's why (1) works. The type `::S` is not found because name lookup finds the injected class name and never looks in the enclosing scope (if it *did* find `::S` the code wouldn't compile, because `::S` is not a base class of `X`).

As an analogy consider this example using a member typedef declared in `D::S`:

```
namespace D {
  struct S {
    struct S { S(){std::cout << "D::S\n";} };
    typedef S AnotherName;
  };
}

struct X : D::S {
  X() : AnotherName() { }
};
```

This works because the name `AnotherName` is found in the base class, and is a synonym for the type of the base class, `D::S`. The injected class name works similarly, except that the name that gets injected is the class' own name, `S`, not some other name like `AnotherName`.

> - Are (1) and (2) both required to work?

Yes.

(2) works because `D::S` is the fully-qualified named of `S` so it refers to the same type, but using its "full name" that non-members must use to refer to the type.

> - Why does S s; inside f() refer to D::S and not ::S ?

Because like the constructor, `f()` is a member of `X` so name lookup looks inside the scope of `X` (and its base classes) first, and so finds the injected class name. It never see the type `::S` at global scope because it finds the name `S` as a member of the base class and stops looking.